# Accessing API: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

Tags: python, api

I am trying to access an API using the ETL tool Alteryx, but receive the error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'
```

I am able to run the code in Python 2.7.16 just fine, but the version within Alteryx is 3.6.0.  I had to change the JSONRPC file where xmlrpclib was to xmlrpc.client.  I then got `No module named 'httplib'`.  I had to change httplib to http.client.  Next, I got the error `Cannot import name 'HTTP'`.  I saw the line that had `from httplib import HTTP, HTTPConnection` and I removed `HTTP`.  Lastly, I used a web 2to3 python converter for the `jsonrpc` file, and added in the line `from urllib.parse import (splittype, splithost)` in the `jsonrpc` package. I am now to the final two lines, but running into the encoding argument error.

I have tried to install `msgpack`, remove the encoding arguments in `__init__.py`, and change cls = encoding in `__init__.py` for json in CurrentDirectory\Lib\json.

```py
import pprint
from jsonrpclib import jsonrpc
from datetime import datetime
Transaction_Code = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
givex = jsonrpc.ServerProxy("host:port")
response = givex.dc_1026('en', Transaction_Code, 'ID', 'password', 'reportname','','')
pprint.pprint(response)
```

I expect the JSON output for the data, but I receive the following Traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Program Files\Alteryx\bin\Miniconda3\PythonTool_venv\lib\site-packages\jsonrpclib\jsonrpc.py", line 289, in **call**
    return self.**send(self.__name, args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Alteryx\bin\Miniconda3\PythonTool_venv\lib\site-packages\jsonrpclib\jsonrpc.py", line 237, in _request
    rpcid=rpcid, version=self.__version)
  File "C:\Program Files\Alteryx\bin\Miniconda3\PythonTool_venv\lib\site-packages\jsonrpclib\jsonrpc.py", line 532, in dumps
    return jdumps(request, encoding=encoding)
  File "C:\Program Files\Alteryx\bin\Miniconda3\PythonTool_venv\lib\site-packages\jsonrpclib\jsonrpc.py", line 98, in jdumps
    return json.dumps(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "C:\Program Files\Alteryx\bin\Miniconda3\lib\json__init**.py", line 238, in dumps
    """
TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

Comment: I think that 1) the traceback you posted is incomplete; and 2) the module is now messed up, so you'd better just reinstall it

Comment: I copied the traceback directly from python, so I am not sure what it could be missing.  2) All the changes I made, I have a copy of the original file, so I can revert any.  Which module do you believe should be corrected?

Comment: I thought there should be a line of code after `File "<string>", line 1`, but apparently that's not the case. It seems the exception is generated by a line of code you're inputting into the interactive session because otherwise Python would put the name of the file instead of `"<string>"`. You should probably reinstall the `jsonrpclib` module via `pip3` or whatever package manages Miniconda provides.

Comment: So `jdumps` is trying to do `json.dumps(obj, encoding=encoding)`. This was fine in Python 2, but in Python 3 the `encoding` keyword has been removed. `jsonrpclib` has had a [pull request](https://github.com/joshmarshall/jsonrpclib/pull/59) open to make it Python 3 compatible since 2017, you might want to switch to the `jsonrpclib-pelix` fork, that one should be compatible with Python 3.

Comment: Thank you Rick! I had a few issues with Alteryx trying to reinstall python and its packages, finally uninistalled, reinstalled it, and got jsonrpclib-pelix instead and it works as desired!!! Thank you SOOOOO much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help from @[rickdenhaan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1941241/rickdenhaan) I had to use jsonrpclib-pelix instead of jsonrpclib in Python 3.6